# How to save an object from matchit

Tags: r, matching

I  created an object using matchit.

```
require(MatchIt)

match.obj <- matchit(ps.formula, data =pts_raw_ps,
                     distance = pts_raw_ps$PS,
                     method = "nearest",
                     ratio = 1,
                     caliper = .2*sd(pts_raw_ps$logitPS))
```

I want to save the object so that I can use it later.
I tried to save it in RData file.
But when I reloaded it, it was denatured.

What is the good way to save such an object, then reuse it for subsequent analyses.

Comment: Try [`saveRDS`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) or [`save`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html).